git diff list of files on github action's PR
When I open a pull request, I have a github action set to trigger a node script:
name: Check i18n tokens 
on:
    pull_request:
        types: [labeled, unlabeled, opened, synchronize, reopened]
        branches: ['master']
jobs:
    check-I18N-tokens:
        needs: generate-matrix
        # A check job is performed for each element present in needs.generate-matrix.outputs.matrix. If empty ([]), the job is skipped.
        if: ${{ !contains(needs.generate-matrix.outputs.matrix, '[]') }}
        strategy:
            matrix: ${{ fromJSON(needs.generate-matrix.outputs.matrix) }}
        runs-on: [self-hosted, cdorunner-life-novum, Linux]
        container: xxx
        steps:
            - name: checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@v4
            - name: Install dependencies
              run: yarn
            - name: Performing the check
              run: yarn perform list-files-changed
...


Where the script performs something like the following:
const currentBranch = execSync('git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD', {encoding: 'utf8'}).trim();
const diffFilesOutput = execSync(`git diff --name-only $(git merge-base ${currentBranch} master)`, {
    encoding: 'utf8',
});
const filesToCheck = diffFilesOutput.split(/\r?\n/).filter((file) => file.endsWith('.tsx'));
console.log(filesToCheck);

now, it used to work on github actions, but now I got the following:
fatal: Not a valid object name master

so I'm here asking: is there a way to diff the PR against master, without checking out the whole repo? it's huge and it'd save a lot of resources (and time)
Update
I've found a discussion that could be related to this: github checkout discussion

is there a way to diff the PR against master, without checking out the whole repo? Idea: clone shallow master and run diff. Another idea: use github api.

@KamilCuk I was thinking about git fetch origin master, in place of cloning master. is that possible? Plus, not sure I could use git merge-base that way? I do want it to get the exact list of paths I need

git fetch origin master, in place of cloning master. is that possible? Why don't you try it? How does it differ from "checking out the whole repo"? Just then do normal checkout fetch-depth: 0 see https://github.com/actions/checkout .

@Bertuz If you don't need much beyond the tip commit of the branch to run the diff against: git fetch --depth=1 origin master

When you use default actions/checkout@v4, you are only checking out the latest commit of your branch and no other refs. Therefore, ref ‘master’ is not known.
The easiest way to fix this is
steps:
  - name: Checkout Repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v4
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0

Alternatively, you could try
git fetch
git diff origin/master


I simply want to git diff with the branch PR, checkout would be too much. I'm wondering if git fetch origin master would work the same? I've tried but unsuccessfully

Try using fetch - see updated answer.
